# How to know whether a laptop supports aptX-HD or not?

Tags: laptop, bluetooth

I wonder how to know whether a laptop supports aptX-HD or not (without dongle)?

I want to buy a laptop as a streamer and need it to support aptX-HD. After searching I found it very hard to know which one supports aptX-HD because they don't mention it explicitly in the specs. Is there anyway to know it by like CPU model or OS version or any explicit specs? Thank you.

Comment: If you're on a modern Linux distribution, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/425334/231221

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately while many Bluetooth network chips support these advanced features, the driver support is usually missing or disabled. Newer and high-end cards from Intel and Killer branded cards should be able to support newer AptX codecs, but you may have to get drivers directly instead of from the laptop's support page.

It should be possible for a software implementation, but Microsoft only licensed the baseline AptX implementation. Maybe in the future there will be a store app to unlock this functionality.